# Reverse Generated Items & Tab Order of ItemsControl Collection

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, itemscontrol

So as we know an `ItemsControl` will just generate the Items top-to-bottom in its ItemsPanel. Where as yes I can change the sort order and generate them in different ways here's my actual problem.

If I have an `ItemsControl` using an `ItemTemplate` with multiple `UIElement`'s and use for example, a `StackPanel` as the `ItemsPanel` I end up with a natural tab order of something like;

```
a. 1  2  3  4  5
b. 6  7  8  9  10
c. 11 12 13 14 15
```

Expected, which I could use either the order of placement or `FlowDirection` on the `ItemTemplate` to obviously get;

```
a. 5  4  3  2  1
b. 10 9  8  7  6
c. 15 14 13 12 11
```

Now, my question is how could I achieve? (in the most efficient way) an order more like;

```
C. 11 12 13 14 15
B. 6  7  8  9  10
A. 1  2  3  4  5
```

Now then if you're thinking.. "ugh, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> dummy..." well I wish it was an option. The requirement is just using tab, and generating the collection in reverse bottom to top instead of top to bottom and having the tab order reversed while they're in that control. Is it wise to try and hijack the shift/tab event and convert it to just tab somehow? Even if that were the case it only answers part of my question.

Hopefully someones ran into this before or enjoys an interesting question so any insight is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: So is each of a, b and c an ItemsControl with a StackPanel in it, and then the 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 etc are inside the StackPanel? What container are a, b and c in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up inheriting from `StackPanel` and just custom reversing it for the `ItemPanel`. Was such a dumb solution after it was figured out that almost feel embarrassed for asking for help haha. Thanks though to whomever might have taken a moment to consider it.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried a simple example with a StackPanel of StackPanels (ie no data binding), and it seems that flow direction has no impact on vertically stacked panels (it would be nice if there was a TopToBottom, or BottomToTop option).

I think your data model needs to be (conceptually) a list of lists, and then you need to make an ItemsControl of ItemsControls (I know it's a pain to layout but it can be done), and you'll have to order the outer list backwards so that the controls are generated C, B, A (because the FlowDirection doesn't do anything in the vertical orientation).

Comment: Not completely sure I understand what you mean? The problem I keep having, is the lack of being able to reverse the vertical order, not sure how a ItemsControl of ItemsControls would work? Are you saying generate an item in one, and use it to populate another?